# WebClient issue with JAVA_OPTS

Tags: reactor-netty

I encountered an issue where I couldn't retrieve proxy settings provided via JAVA_OPTS for my WebClient running in PCF, currently I must add the configuration programmatically. However, the RestTemplate version appears to work correctly with these settings.

Before sharing my source code and logs, I'm wondering if there's a straightforward update I might have missed, which I can test on my end first. This way, I can ensure that I've covered all potential solutions before raising a new question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.